# Flutter: How to stream only one field in a firestore document?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

How do you, or is it even possible to, stream only one field in a firestore document.  I would like to stream the data for only one key value which is a List?  For example:

```
DocumentSnapshot {
    'firstname':'Joe',
    'lastname':'Smith',
    'friendsList': [one@one.com, two@two.com, three@three.com]
}
```

Can I stream only the 'friendsList' field or do I have to pull the whole DocumentSnapshot ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of a document is an atomic unit.  If it's read by the user account, then entire document will always be transferred and cached as a unit.  There are no partial document reads.

In the interest of speeding up requests, you might choose to split the contents of a single document into multiple documents among multiple collections, so that only the minimal amount of information is fetched for different use cases that require different fields.  Splitting up a document like this is also good for protecting different fields with different security rules.